# I am not able to get the updated internalStorage value instantly to update my cart notification in Reactjs

Tags: reactjs, axios, local-storage, cart, updating

this my cart Icon which is a separate cart component

```
 <IconButton aria-label="cart">
     <StyledBadge badgeContent={localStorage.getItem('count')} 
                  color="primary">
         <ShoppingCartIcon style={IconStyling.styleListShopIcon} />
     </StyledBadge>
 </IconButton>
```

This is mine code to update localStorage while posting new cart item

```js
axios.post(`http://localhost:5000/cart`, CartData)
    .then((result) => {
        localStorage.setItem('count', result.data.length);
    }).catch((error) => {
        console.log(error)
    })
```

Comment: keep the value in state and on axios response set state and use that state in template. don't use localstorage directly it won't update virtual dom directly.

Comment: it doesn't look like you are doing anything that will trigger a render, so the change won't show up until some other action does.

Answer (score 0):

React uses references to check if something changed in order to trigger updates.

By using `localStorage` the reference would be always the same and it won't trigger updates.

A "hacky" way to basically keep everything you have is something like this:

Add a state to the component you want to render and a `forceRender` function:

```js
  const [render, setRender] = React.useState(0)
  function forceRender(){
    setRender(render + 1)
  }
```

Then add `forceRender` to your Axios fetch:

```js
axios.post(`http://localhost:5000/cart`, CartData)
    .then((result) => {
        localStorage.setItem('count', result.data.length);
        forceRender();
    }).catch((error) => {
        console.log(error)
    })
```

Beware that this would be you literally telling react when to rerender and there are better ways to do this builtin...

Comment: what if i need to pass that render into another component which is cart component in this case should i use context api  because using props passing it to all intermediate components is head rolling for me to understand do u hae any better idea

Comment: what I would actually do is, yes, use context api and then probably a class (or just functions) that will handle all the connections to the localStorage, store the values in a useState or useReduce and then when you need to update the values you update in the state and call the abstraction to persist on localStorage